# ¿Cómo dar este formato al ID con AUTO_INCREMENT en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estoy trabajando con MYSQL y tengo una base de datos llamada prueba y una tabla llamada formulario, en la cual el campo ID es AUTO_INCREMENT y comienza desde 1. Pero lo que necesito es que comience de 001 en adelante.
He visto algunos ejemplos, pero no me han funcionado como establecer el AUTO_INCREMENT = 001.
Espero que alguien me pueda orientar o indicar que le falta a mi query.

```
  CREATE TABLE `prueba`.`formulario` ( 
  `id` INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  `nombre_usuario` VARCHAR(50) NULL, `correo_usuario` VARCHAR(100) NULL,  
  `estado_solicitud` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'ENVIADO', 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 001;
```

Al ejecutar esta query e ingresar un registro comienza desde 1.

Comment: SBK22, Un entero por sí mismo no tiene 0s a la izquierda. El número y el funcionamiento de la base de datos es correcto. Otra cosa sería ya cómo mostrarlo en una página (si el destino es ese), en el que sí podrías rellenar con esos ceros el dato mostrado (bien directamente desde la consulta MySQL o bien, más recomendable, desde el lenguaje de programación que utilices)

Comment: si queres que el autonumerico represente otra cosa, entonces no tenes que usar un autonumerico.. porque querrias que fuera 001??? sabias que el autonumerico puede dejar agujeros y otras cosas?

Comment: El formato que actualmente ocupo en mis planillas excel es 001, y al llevar esto al sistema mi intención era mantener este formato.

Comment: Formato se aplica a cadenas, no a enteros. El campo en la tabla, al ser de tipo entero no soporta *formato*. Excel por su parte aplica un formato visual al valor de la celda, eso no lo puedes hacer sobre un campo de tipo entero en la base de datos.

Comment: Una cosa es lo que guardas y otra, lo que _pintas_. Cuando lo uses al pintar, imprimir y todo eso, le das el formato que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, me quedo muy claro....